# Get count from latest hour per day using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a Raw Data table in Power BI where I am trying to count the number of jobs performed in the last hour of each day, preferably using DAX.

A representation of the table can be built in DAX using (the actual table is built from various CSV files in Power Query):

```
Raw Data = { 
( "A", "42784", DATE( 2022, 8, 31 ), 5 ), 
( "A", "91783", DATE( 2022, 8, 31 ), 5 ), 
( "A", "19845", DATE( 2022, 8, 31 ), 6 ), 
( "A", "76165", DATE( 2022, 8, 31 ), 6 ), 
( "A", "28253", DATE( 2022, 8, 31 ), 7 ), 
( "A", "83294", DATE( 2022, 8, 31 ), 8 ), 
( "A", "47431", DATE( 2022, 8, 31 ), 9 ), 
( "A", "20025", DATE( 2022, 8, 31 ), 10 ), 
( "A", "10564", DATE( 2022, 8, 31 ), 10 ), 
( "A", "65463", DATE( 2022, 8, 31 ), 10 ), 
( "B", "44750", DATE( 2022, 9, 1 ), 5 ), 
( "B", "47302", DATE( 2022, 9, 1 ), 6 ), 
( "B", "31759", DATE( 2022, 9, 1 ), 6 ), 
( "B", "26638", DATE( 2022, 9, 1 ), 7 ), 
( "B", "55076", DATE( 2022, 9, 1 ), 7 ), 
( "B", "59205", DATE( 2022, 9, 1 ), 8 ), 
( "B", "52319", DATE( 2022, 9, 1 ), 8 )
 }
```

[image]

I then have a second table built in DAX which gives me the unique date values (the actual table copies the date column from a date table - which is itself sourced from the raw data)

```
Dimension = CALENDAR(FIRSTDATE('Raw Data'[Value3]), LASTDATE('Raw Data'[Value3]))
```

The problem comes when I add a column to try and count how many items were processed in the last hour on each day.
Items are counted by counting the `Value 2` column.  Hour of the day is shown in the `Value 4` column.
So 3 items on 31st August at 10 o'clock, 2 items on 1st September at 8 o'clock.

The DAX I'm using for this is:

```
LatestUnitsProcessed = 
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Raw Data'[Value2] ),
    FILTER (
        FILTER ( 'Raw Data', 'Raw Data'[Value3] = 'Dimension'[Date] ),
        'Raw Data'[Value4] = MAX('Raw Data'[Value4])
    )
)
```

[image]

This correctly returns 3 for 31st August, but leaves 1st September blank.  Pretty sure this is because `MAX('Raw Data'[Value4])` is ignoring the date and trying to see how many were processed at 10 o'clock on the 1st.

How would I include the data criteria to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

This creates a virtual relationship.

```
LatestUnitsProcessed = 

VAR last = CALCULATE(MAX('Raw Data'[Value4]), TREATAS({'Dimension'[Date]} ,'Raw Data'[Value3]))
RETURN 
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Raw Data'[Value2] ),
    TREATAS({'Dimension'[Date]} ,'Raw Data'[Value3]),
    'Raw Data'[Value4] = last
)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works.... even better, it works on my 100,000 row table as well. :)

Comment: Hopefully I'm doing this correctly in my working model - this has a Calendar Date table in addition to the Raw Data and Dimension tables.  Raw Data > Calendar Date is m:1 relationship and Dimension > Calendar Date is 1:1 relationship.  Would it be correct to update the `TREATAS` clause to `TREATAS({'Dimension'[Date]}, 'Date'[DATE])`?  Seems to work, but checking in case there's any hidden pitfalls.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the full model but treatas is just creating a virtual relationship. If you can use a physical one, do so but if it is a calculated column, it doesn't really matter. Personally, I would avoid using calculated DAX columns entirely as they can slow model development down and if I need calculated columns, I would do these in M/Power Query and reserve DAX just for measures.

Comment: Cheers for the info.  I can see it slowing down model development..... took me most of the day to get to where I was before asking the question on here. :)  I already had it working in PQ but trying to get my head around DAX as well.  A big part is when to use PQ and when to use DAX.

Comment: Yeah, you learn these things with experience. My suggestion is use DAX just for measures. Calculated columns and tables should typically be done in PQ. As long as you shape your data correctly and build a good model, the DAX should be relatively straightforward.

Comment: When I say it slows model development, I mean every new measure you create means the DAX engine will recalculate every model object - more calculated columns means more time waiting and this mounts up if you have to write a lot of measures.

Comment: Thought that was what you meant.  Pretty much everything is slow going in Power BI for me at the moment.  Anyway.... best stop chatting.... website is starting to complain.

Answer (score 0):

try this with relationship (Dimension --> Value3)...

```
LatestUnitsProcessed =
VAR _max =
    MAX ( 'Raw Data'[Value4] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Raw Data'[Value2] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Raw Data', 'Raw Data'[Value3] ),
        'Raw Data'[Value4] = _max
    )
```

[Sample File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j7iHKj0c4JqD_6GXennuiY5R0aEhnnBL/view?usp=sharing)

[image: realtions]

[image: LatestUnits]

Comment: Thanks for the answer Umut.  I was getting 3 returns for 1st September as well - even with the relationship in place.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook with your given dummy data, i get 2 as a result as I've posted in my answer...

Comment: Yes, can see that in your image.  Couldn't understand why I was getting 3 and not 2.  I just copied your answer into my Power BI dummy set and it returned 3....

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook check my sample file, it still shows 2 )))